# Implement interface declared in innerclass

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

Here is a Java question
How can I implement the inner class's interface in outer class?

I try the following, but in vain. Thank You

```
class A implements interface B.C{
   static class B{
        interface C{

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `implements A.B.C`. But why?

Comment: but eclipse return  cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this :
Assuming both the classes are in same package with proper imports.

```
public class Nestedinterface {
     public interface NestI{
         void show();
     }
}

public class NestedinterfaceImpl implements NestI {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        NestI n = new NestedinterfaceImpl();
        n.show();
    }
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello world");    
    }
}
```